# Xamarin Forms: no method with name='getDrawable' signature='(I)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;' in class Landroid/content/Context;

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I downloaded this project: https://github.com/adamped/Instagram
and when I run it I get this exception:

> Unhandled Exception:
>
> Java.Lang.NoSuchMethodError: no method with name='getDrawable'
>   signature='(I)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;' in class
>   Landroid/content/Context;

in this class:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Entry), typeof(TextViewCustomRenderer))] namespace Instagram.Droid.Renderers {     public class TextViewCustomRenderer: EntryRenderer  {

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)      {           base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Control != null)    
    {
                /*This throws the exception*/Control.Background = Android.App.Application.Context.GetDrawable(Resource.Drawable.rounded_corners);
                Control.Gravity = GravityFlags.CenterVertical;
                Control.SetPadding(10, 0, 0, 0);            }       }

    } }
```

I tried to change the compilation version from Oreo to Nougat, but with no avail!

It seems I don't know what this exception is about!

please help.

Answer (score 0):

The `getDrawable` got deprecated. You can try to use this:

```
this.Control.Background = ContextCompat.GetDrawable(Forms.Context, Resource.Layout.YourDrawableId);
```

Comment: Warning: 'Resources.GetDrawable(int)' is obsolete: 'deprecated'